# Reading values/attributes from external *.txt file

Tags: leaflet, html5

The following code works fine. When I click the "Test Play/Stop" button a series of points from the 'geojson' list are drawn with popup attributes one by one.

How can I put the list 'geojson' as geojson.txt file in my hard disk and access that file in the following code? This way I can save so many lines in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.2/leaflet-src.js">    </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Popcen.css" />
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false">        </script>
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet-google.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="span9" style="height:100%">
     <div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9999; width: 100%; height: 100%">
          <div id="button-information">
              <input type="button" id="Pause1" value="Test Play/Stop"     onclick="myHit()"   class="btnStyle span2" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<script>
    {
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(28.1, 84.1), 7);
    }
</script>
  <script>  

    var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, maxZoom:     12}).setView([28.1,84.1], 7);

var keepRunning = false;

myHit = function()
{
keepRunning = !keepRunning;    
console.log(keepRunning);

    var geojson = { type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[28.24, 84.75, 7.6, .45, '04/25/2015', '11:56', 'Gorkha'], [28.41, 85.8, 5.5, .12, '04/25/2015', '12:23', 

'Sindhupalchowk/Tibet'], [28.28, 84.72, 6.6, .18, '04/25/2015', '12:30', 'Gorkha'], [28.13, 85.65, 5.7, .2, '04/25/2015', '12:41', 'Rasuwa'], [28.2, 85.75, 5.3, .65, '04/25/2015', 

'12:53', 'Rasuwa'], [27.99, 85.71, 5.1, .5, '04/25/2015', '13:32', 'Tibet'], [27.78, 85.84, 5.2, .05, '04/25/2015', '14:02', 'Sindhupalchowk'], [27.9, 84.86, 5.1, .15, '04/25/2015', 

'14:05', 'Dhading'], [28.18, 84.95, 5.2, .43, '04/25/2015', '14:14', 'Gorkha'], [27.65, 85.63, 5.7, .13, '04/25/2015', '14:40', 'Kabre'], [27.91, 85.33, 5.3, .45, '04/25/2015', '14:48', 

'Rasuwa'], [28, 85.6, 5.5, .22, '04/25/2015', '15:15', 'Sindhupalchowk'], [28.29, 85.16, 4.6, .67, '04/25/2015', '15:28', 'Rasuwa'], [27.87, 85.8, 4.1, .28, '04/25/2015', '16:08', 

'Sindhupalchowk'], [27.86, 85.85, 4, .42, '04/25/2015', '16:25',     'Sindhupalchowk'], [27.91, 85.5, 4.6, .6, '04/25/2015', '16:50', 'Sindhupalchowk'], [28.14, 85.28, 4.1, .6, 

'04/25/2015', '17:26', 'Rasuwa'], [28, 85.4, 4.9, .37, '04/25/2015', '18:02', 'Nuwakot'], [27.82, 86.05, 4.5, .08, '04/25/2015', '18:24', 'Dolakha'], [28.16, 84.71, 5.5, .77, 

'04/25/2015', '18:29', 'Gorkha'], [28.1, 85.2, 4.7, .1, '04/25/2015', '19:15', 'Rasuwa'], [27.69, 86.02, 4.9, .28, '04/25/2015', '19:21', 'Dolakha'], [27.79, 85.16, 4.1, .15, 

'04/25/2015', '19:38', 'Nuwakot'], [27.68, 85.32, 4.1, .13, '04/25/2015', '19:47', 'Kathmandu'], [27.73, 85.9, 4.7, .22, '04/25/2015', '19:55', 'Sindhupalchowk'], [28.05, 85.25, 4.1, 

.22, '04/25/2015', '20:08', 'Rasuwa'], [27.6, 86.09, 4.5, .07, '04/25/2015', '20:21', 'Dolakha'], [27.73, 85.9, 5, .18, '04/25/2015', '20:25', 'Sindhupalchowk'], [28.14, 85.16, 4.4, 

.43, '04/25/2015', '20:36', 'Rasuwa']]};

var hitSequence = L.marker([26, 80]).addTo(map);

loop(0,0);
var t = 0;
function loop(t){
   map.removeLayer(hitSequence);
   hitSequence = new L.marker([geojson.coordinates[t][0], geojson.coordinates[t][1]]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Attribute1:  </b>" + geojson.coordinates[t][6] + '<br>' + 

"<b>Attribute2:  </b>" + geojson.coordinates[t][2] + '<br>' + "<b>Attribute3:  </b>" + geojson.coordinates[t][4] + '<br>' + "<b>Attribute4:  </b>" + geojson.coordinates[t]

[5]).openPopup();
   if (t>geojson.coordinates.length){t=0;}
    if(keepRunning){
       setTimeout(function() {loop(++t);}, geojson.coordinates[t][3]*3000);
    }
    else{map.removeLayer(hitSequence);}
   }   
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to put everything from `var geojson = {` down to the closing `};` into a new file and loading that as JavaScript file in the head of your HTML.

For example:

geojson_data.js:

```
var geojson = {

 type: 'LineString', coordinates: [

  [28.24, 84.75, 7.6, .45, '04/25/2015', '11:56', 'Gorkha'],

  [28.41, 85.8, 5.5, .12, '04/25/2015', '12:23', 'Sindhupalchowk/Tibet'],

...

  [28.14, 85.16, 4.4, .43, '04/25/2015', '20:36', 'Rasuwa']

 ]

};
```

And in your  section add:

```
<script src="geojson_data.js"></script>
```